# Convert string of numbers into numeric data type in R

Tags: r

I have a 10x1 matrix of character (say e212m).

```
> print(e212m)
      [,1]                          
  [1,] "0000000000000111111000000000"
  [2,] "0000000000000111111100000000"
  [3,] "0000000000001111111100000000"
  [4,] "0000000000001111111100000000"
  [5,] "0000000000011100111100000000"
  [6,] "0000000000011111111100000000"
  [7,] "0000000000011111111100000000"
  [8,] "0000000000011111111100000000"
  [9,] "0000000000001111111000000000"
  [10,] "0000000000000011111000000000"
  > dim(e212m)
  [1] 10  1
  > typeof(e212m)
  [1] "character"
```

I want to convert each character of any row into integer. But not like

```
"0000000000000111111000000000"(string/character) to integer = 0000000000000111111000000000
```

I want something like each character changed to digit.eg

```
"0" "0" "1" "1" to number 0 0 1 1.
```

So that in the end I can get integer matrix of 10x29.
P.S: I am new to R. Direct commands doing the above task are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x<-"0000000000000111111000000000"
y<-as.numeric(strsplit(x,split='')[[1]])
```

will return

```
y
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

if you matrix is named m just use :

```
m2<-apply(m,1,function(x){as.numeric(strsplit(x,split='')[[1]])})
m2<-t(m2)
```

Comment: what does 1 in square brackets in the end mean?

Comment: And also for the 10 rows do I need to use for loop? Would be very grateful if you could guide me in that.

Comment: the `[[1]]` selects the first element of a list (because `strsplit` returns a list). I added an edit for converting the matrix in one time

Comment: ^Thank you.. that worked.. I just had to transpose the matrix to suit my need.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("0000000000000111111000000000", "0000000000000111111100000000", "0000000000001111111100000000")
y <- paste(x, collapse = "\n")
read.fwf(textConnection(y), rep(1, nchar(x[1])))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28
#1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression.

```
gsub('(\\d)','\\1 ',x)
```

or

```
gsub('(?<=\\d)(\\d)',' \\1',x,perl=T)
```